# Prove the proposed statement is a tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Question

$$((p\vee q)\wedge\neg(\neg p\wedge(\neg q\vee\neg r)))\vee(\neg p\wedge\neg q)\vee(\neg p\wedge \neg r)$$

Show that this statement is a tautology without using truth table.

I am trying to solve this by laws of logic but couldn't get the answer. Help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What inference rules are you allowed? What have you tried? Do you mean theorem or are you looking for a metalogic proof?

Comment: Which laws of logic are you allowed to use?

Comment: Laws of logic like distribution law, association laws etc.